# Use oauth-php to fetch own company updates with LinkedIn

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

I need to use [oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) to authenticate with the LinkedIn API.  I want to fetch LinkedIn status updates from my own company's LinkedIn profile.  LinkedIn gives a great example how to retrieve your own LinkedIn profile [on their website](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide#toggleview%3aid=php) with the PHP OAuth extension, but I can't figure out how to do it with the oauth-php library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Company Update](https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-updates) docs, you would make a call using oauth-php to the following endpoint:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates
```

Comment: This is correct, but I need to go through authentication first and my question is how to do the equivalent process on their [getting started page](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide) with oauth-php instead of using the OAuth PHP extension.

Comment: There is a [three-legged demo](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo) right on the code site - LinkedIn follows that model.